# Update BigQuery table when Datastore updates

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google Web Application connected to a Google App Engine back-end, using Datastore to store all of my data.

I have followed this tutorial: http://www.smartgooglecloud.com/gcs/bigquery/datastore-export-to-bigquery-part-1-manual-export/ to send my data from my Datastore to BigQuery. I was wondering if there is anyway to update the BigQuery table when my datastore updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, no. You can write your own script to update BigQuery as often as you need. But it loads from datastore *backups*, so you'd have to make a new backup every time your datastore updates, which is not feasible.

You might want to have a look at [streaming data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery).